# Listing files in rpm archive

Tags: package-management, rpm

What is the difference in the following 2 commands:

```
rpm -qlp <filename>.rpm

rpm -qilp <filename>.rpm
```

I know the `-i` flag is for install but how does that relate to producing different outputs, as in the following example:

```
[vagrant@10 ~]$ rpm -qlp nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.54.el7.x86_64.rpm | wc -l
98
[vagrant@10 ~]$ rpm -qilp nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.54.el7.x86_64.rpm | wc -l
127
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `rpm` is called in query mode `-q`, the `-i` flag is for displaying package information not for install.

From the man page of `rpm`:

```
PACKAGE QUERY OPTIONS:  

  -i, --info  
      Display package information, including name, version, 
      and description. This uses the --queryformat if one was specified.
```

You can easily see the difference if do not pipe the output to `wc` but rather look at the output of your commands. For example:

```
diff <(rpm -qlp nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.54.el7.x86_64.rpm) <(rpm -qilp nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.54.el7.x86_64.rpm)
```

Comment: thanks for this; however I noticed that these two flags, i.e. `-q` and `-i` cannot be combined alone; `[vagrant@10 ~]$ rpm -qi nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.54.el7.x86_64.rpm
package nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.54.el7.x86_64.rpm is not installed`

Comment: @pkaramol: They work together just fine, but without `p` you need to specify the name of an installed package.